# Complex heirarchical tree layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree, d3.js

I need to create an hierarchical tree ([something like this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/999346)), but i need some features:

1. Ability to design the nodes as i like (size, background image, fonts etc.)
2. Automatic layout
3. Ability to connect nodes by drag N' drop

I've looked at [GoJs](http://gojs.net/) and its great, but it's canvas based, and i couldn't find a way to make the nodes look exactly as I want (actually not even remotely close).

I've also looked at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) which is also great but again, since it's SVG it's haard to design the nodes.

The main hustle here is the layout, and connecting the nodes, i can handle the Drag N' Drop my self, Is there a library out there that can handle the layout for me , so i can create the required div's, design them as i see fit and let the library do just the layout stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some sample libraries.

If you want to avoid canvas, try implementing drag n drop for the following

[CSS3 Family Tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree)

[SlickMap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/)

or else see some canvas based libraries

[JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit's HyperTree / SpaceTree](http://philogb.github.com/jit/demos.html)

[jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/chartDemo.html)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst a late answer, hopefully it can help others in the future.
Here is a drag and drop tree utilising the excellent D3.js library.

http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

https://gist.github.com/robschmuecker/7880033

The tree in the example handles automatic layout/sizing, zooming, panning, drag and drop and is collapsible. All or none of the aspects can be removed if needed.

Comment: This is a cool solution, but breaks down horribly for any large number of nodes.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Hi, have you had a look at my example with 50,000 Nodes?

http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7926762
This relates to another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539922/has-anyone-produced-a-virtualised-javascript-tree-for-thousands-of-nodes

Comment: JS in general can handle 100k+ nodes in memory fine. Figuring out a way to render them--that's another problem. There's no windowing or clipping, so an expanded tree above around 1,000 nodes is unusuably slow.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Yes I agree, this does become somewhat cumbersome on larger amounts of expanded nodes.  Whilst the threshold is somewhat hardware dependant, using the example above with a reduced amount of JSON to 2800 nodes I still get acceptable performance with all nodes expanded. http://jsfiddle.net/E4TXc/  However for anything above this it would certainly get sluggish/unusable depending on the number of the nodes expanded.

Comment: Have you considered some kind of viewport calculation that would omit nodes from the SVG that are both unconnected to a visible node and outside the current window coordinates? (Is such a thing even readily possible with D3?)

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Yes that would/could be possible I'm sure, however there would be associated lag/delay on every drag/zoom event which would make it somewhat uncomfortable to use.  I implemented this on a system where I know that I will never need more than 2000 nodes and hence haven't had to really consider such intricacies thoroughly.

Comment: The point was to somehow mitigate the delay which already occurs on larger layouts by omitting irrelevant nodes from the calculation. Presumably one could stash parent node links as readily as child, if needed, and could thus perform some viewport-sensitive updating which (if implemented correctly) would never require traversing (or updating) significantly more nodes than were on-screen. It's a thought, anyway.