# Has anyone produced a virtualised javascript tree for thousands of nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, virtualization

I'm trying to move an application to the web that contains a tree of up to 50,000 nodes. I first tried to produce this using jqxtree widget, but the DOM was far too large and they clearly don't support thousands of nodes.

I'm looking for a virtualised solution and while I've seen several examples of lists containing millions of items, I've yet to see one working with a tree. Has anyone else made this? Is it possible?

The tree doesn't require any features like drag and drop. It's just an expand/collapse/click event thing.

Comment: If it's such a simple task you could try to code it. Around 99.9% of the time will be spent in the browser's rendering process. I have no idea how you're going to "virtualize" it though.

Comment: You won't be able to add so many nodes into the dom without having any performance problems. You should think about just rendering the root nodes and then load the childs via Ajax.

Comment: I had thought of ajax requests but it's likely that the user will expand folders to many thousands of nodes. This is why I was thinking of the virtualization used to create lists of millions of items, where you allow the user to scroll and throw into the DOM whatever is in the view. I'm not sure how doable that is with a tree though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try jstree [extension of jquery](https://www.jstree.com/)

> When using AJAX set children to boolean true and jsTree will render the node as closed and make an additional request for that node when the user opens it.

[core data](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.core.data)

Answer (score 12):

I can recommend using the excellent [d3.js](http://www.d3js.org) library.
I have made a test setup based on a previous git gist of mine here: http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7926762
With the gist being here:
https://gist.github.com/robschmuecker/7926762

There are over 50,000 nodes there, however for performance it is important that the children start off collapsed. If that is the case I have found the performance to be very acceptable on a modern browser. The tree is expandable, auto-sizing, zoomable, drag&droppable.

The original code that this is based off is here:
https://gist.github.com/robschmuecker/7880033

Comment: Hello @Rob Schmuecker, your app looks and performs great. I have one question. If the data is skewed in the following way: The second level of the tree has say 10 cases and each of these ten has 50 and each of these 50 say 10, but the length of the text of the leaves is quite long then the length of the branches get very very long and zooming in and out does not really help to navigate. How can you adapt the length of the branches so they don't get enormously long? Is it through `children.length` in your code? Thanks

Comment: In d3, the length of the branch is determined by the 'depth'. The spacing between siblings is the 'separation'. Wish I could paste an example... googling it should be ok